# Java: Assigning a variable its current value?

Tags: java, optimization, variable-assignment

If I have a string that is currently empty

```
String s = "";
```

and reassign it

```
s = "";
```

is it bad it I don't do it like this?

```
if(!s.isEmpty()){
   s = "";
}
```

or will the compiler pick up on it and optimize for me?

Comment: The check and branch is far more expensive.  However, if you feel the need to do this on a local variable you might be doing something else wrong like reusing a genericly named variable for an unrelated purpose instead of giving it a meaningful name or avoiding using a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the cost of calling the method isEmpty() (allocating new space in the thread stack etc) negate any gains.  if you want to assign an empty String to the variable, its most efiicient to do so without the if statement.

Comment: Actually, the overhead you mention gets optimized away by inlining, however, you conclusion is right. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30925844/581205).

Answer (score 2):

## Do not micro-pessimize your code.

```
s = "";
```

The assignment gets translated by JIT into a move into register, where the source most probably resides in register as well (in a loop, such an optimization gets done unless you run out of registers). So it's the fastest instruction taking just one cycle and current Intel can execute 4 of them in parallel.

```
if(!s.isEmpty()){
   s = "";
}
```

The function call is not a problem, as it gets inlined. But there's still a memory indirection from the `String` to it's `value.length`. Not bad, but already way more expensive than the simple way. Then a conditional branch, which can take tens of cycles, unless the outcome can be predicted by the CPU. If not, you still may be lucky and the JIT may replace it by a conditional move. *Whatever happens, it can never be faster than the simpler code.*

### Addendum

In theory, you could hope that the JIT finds out that the two variants are equivalent and replaces the pessimized one by the simple one. But these two variants are not equivalent. You'd need to use

```
if (s != "") {
    s = "";
}
```

instead as there may be other empty string than the interned one (i.e., the compile time constant `""`). Anyway, I hope that we agree that the above snippet is something nobody should ever use.

Answer (score 1):

If there's any real logic between the initialization and the point at which you assign `""` again, the compiler probably won't be able to optimize it out. But it's fine if it doesn't, because the reassignment isn't going to take any significant time. In theory, if it did, the Just-In-Time compiler (JIT) in the JVM (well, Oracle's JVM, anyway) would try to optimize it (if it could) if it ended up being a "hot spot" in the code.